# How do I calculate a point between two points with a given distance percentage?

Tags: vector, linear-algebra, direction

I've made a simple drawing:

[image]

The distance between these two points is calculated with a simple formula:

[image]

Which gives: **5,38**

I need to calculate the green point's coordinates, which is set at 80% distance from the `B` point towards the `A` point.

I could make a direction vector between `A` and `B`, and then, add `(dir * 5.38 * 0.8)` to the `B` point itself, but it gives me strange results.

Is there a simpler (and more efficient!) way to achieve that?

Comment: Hint: it's 80% of the way on both axes :)

Comment: There is a formula for it, check out internal division here http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/Maths_Library/Analytical%20Geometry/AnalGeom_3.htm